# lag function doesn't return value to the right direction SQL

Tags: sql, percentage, difference, sql-function

I am trying to find the fastest growing countries based on the number of downloads between 2018 - 2020.

I tried to use the lag function to find the highest growth rate based on the total percentage of increase. However, my result returns all the lag values for `previous_year_downloads` in the wrong order and generated some unknown values, which resulted in the percentage change value being wrong as well.

I have attached my code as shown below:

```
select country,
        year,
        sum(total_downloads) as totals,
        sum(total_downloads) - (lag(sum(total_downloads),1) over(order by year asc)) as previous_year_downloads,
        round((sum(total_downloads) - lag(sum(total_downloads),1) over(order by year asc)) / (lag(sum(total_downloads),1) over (order by year asc)),2) 
        as percentage_change
  from cte
  group by country, year
# i also tried order by year but doesn't work either
```

Below is the sample data generated from google bigquery
[image]

With just one country, all values are in the right order, but with two or more countries, values just appear everywhere and all values except row 1 are not even in the original data frame.

Thank you so much for the help, really appreciate it.

Comment: shouldn't the ordering be by year and country if you want to use lag?

Comment: Hi @topsail, do you mean order by in the `over clause` or I should change the order in my `select clause`? I just tried using `over(order by year, country)` and still doesn't work.

Comment: hmmm you probably want partitioning too - partition by country order by year - this is in the lag function.

Comment: True, i didn't do partition by country that caused the problem, is solved now, thanks for the comment and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know BigQuery but this is how you would do it in sql server.

You probably want year and country in the window function (lag) - that is, partition by countries, then order by years. But perhaps also in the results you will want final ordering so you can see the data as you like to see it (by country, year or by year, country)

```
-- ----------------------------------------------------------------------
-- sample data (the "cte")
declare @cte table (
    country nvarchar(100),
    year int,
    total_downloads int);

insert into @cte values
    ('de', 2018, 10),
    ('fr', 2018, 40),
    ('en', 2020, 20),
    ('fr', 2020, 80),
    ('de', 2020, 25),
    ('en', 2018, 10),
    ('de', 2019, 20),
    ('fr', 2019, 30),
    ('en', 2019, 15);


-- ----------------------------------------------------------------------
-- ugly version
select country,
        year,
        total_downloads as new,
        lag(total_downloads, 1) over(partition by country order by year asc) as old,
        total_downloads - lag(total_downloads, 1) over(partition by country order by country, year asc) as new_minus_old,
        (cast((total_downloads - lag(total_downloads, 1) over(partition by country order by country, year asc)) as decimal(12,3)) / (lag(total_downloads, 1) over(partition by country order by year asc))) as PctChange
from @cte;


-- ----------------------------------------------------------------------
-- cleaner version
select
    T.country,
    T.year,
    T.new,
    T.old,
    T.new - T.old as new_minus_old,
    (T.new - T.old)/cast(T.old as decimal(12,4)) as PctChange
from 
(
    select 
        country, 
        year,
        total_downloads as new,
        lag(total_downloads, 1) over(partition by country order by year asc) as old
    from @cte
) T;
```

Result:

| country | year | new | old | new_minus_old | PctChange |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| de | 2018 | 10 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| de | 2019 | 20 | 10 | 10 | 1.00 |
| de | 2020 | 25 | 20 | 5 | 0.25 |
| en | 2018 | 10 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| en | 2019 | 15 | 10 | 5 | 0.50 |
| en | 2020 | 20 | 15 | 5 | 0.33 |
| fr | 2018 | 40 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| fr | 2019 | 30 | 40 | -10 | -0.25 |
| fr | 2020 | 80 | 30 | 50 | 1.66 |

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to answer the answer, it solved my problem, really appreciate it.